# Makefile target does not recognize dependency action

Tags: makefile

I wrote this simple Makefile to illustrate my problem.

```
$make target
```

- calls the `dep` as a dependency and pulls the image
- But the *subsequent* check for  `docker image list -q $(IMG)` does not find my image.

What is happening here and how should I fix this?

```sh
IMG := hello-world

.PHONY: target
target: dep
ifeq ($(shell docker image list -q $(IMG)),)
        echo "docker image list did not recognize the pull"
endif

.PHONY: dep
dep:
        @docker pull $(IMG)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That test isn't *subsequent*.  It's *substituted* into the Makefile when it's read, before any rules are executed.

You probably want to perform that test in the *commands* of the `target` rule:

```
target: dep
        if test -z "$$(docker image list -q $(IMG))"; then \
            echo "docker image list did not recognize the pull" >&2; \
            false; \
        fi
```

We could change the command to just run `docker image inspect` - that will return a true status if the image exists, and false otherwise:

```
target: dep
        if ! docker image inspect "$(IMG))" >/dev/null 2>&1; then \
            echo "docker image list did not recognize the pull" >&2; \
            false; \
        fi
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps. Few questions. Why did you have to do `$$`? Shouldn't we test it with `[ -z ]` ?

Comment: We don't want Make to expand the shell command substitution - we need to double the `$` to pass it through as `$` to the shell.  Yes, I missed the command name `test` (or `[` `]` if you prefer) - now fixed.